# Calling destructor of non-pointer member before pointer member

Tags: c++, pointers, destructor

Consider three classes like this:

```
class A {
    int bar;
};

class B {
    A* a;
public:
    B(*A na)
    : a(na)
    {}

    ~B() {
        a->bar = 0;
    }
};

class Foo {
    A* a;
    B b;
public:
    Foo()
    : a(new A)
    , b(a)
    {}

    ~Foo() {
        delete a;
    }
};
```

Creating an instance of `Foo`, results in a `Foo` with a pointer to an `A` and a `B` with the same pointer.

When the instance of `Foo` is deleted, The pointer `a` is deleted and then the destructor of `b` is called, but `~B` tries to access `a`, which was freed in `~Foo`, which results in a segmentation fault.

Is there a way to call the destructor of `b` before running the body of `~Foo`?

I know I could solve this, by making either `b` a pointer or making `a` a non-pointer. The latter doesn't work if `A` is abstract and I would like to know if it's possible without making `b` a pointer.

PS: `A` and `B` are both from a library, so I can't change their implementation.

Comment: I expect the missing word (you forgot to type) when you said "making `a` a pointer" was "not" but the missing word should have been "smart".  The clean answer was that `a` should have been a smart pointer, so it is deleted in correct sequence.

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question, but I would suggest just making B a pointer. You can do what you are asking by using a smart pointer, but I think it is a dangerous practice to rely on the order of destruction based on member order unless you have a really good reason, and I don't think this is one. It's better to just make them both pointers and destruct them in the correct order, with a comment explaining why they must be destructed in that order.

Comment: @Gerald, the design clearly must depend on the sequence of construction.  Use of a smart pointer would not create a new dependence on sequence.  It would just depend on destruction sequence being the reverse of construction sequence, which is a rule built into the language (except when you force things otherwise, as the OP did by using a non smart pointer).

Comment: @JSF - If the order of ctor/dtor matters like this, I would prefer to make it explicit, rather than relying on the member order. Yes the rule is built into the language, but that doesn't mean you want to rely on it for convenience. In a team environment especially you are just asking for trouble with this design.

i.e. one day there may come a coding standard that members should be declared in alphabetical order, and maybe they even use a tool to bring the code up to standard, and this is going to break and who knows how long it will take to figure out what happened. (Been there.)

Comment: If they're actually named A and B he will be okay, but somehow I doubt that :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Follow RAII principles.

Change `Foo::a` to `std::unique_ptr<A>`.  Remove the `delete` from `~Foo`.

It will now be destroyed after the end of `~Foo` and after `b.~Bar()`.

Note that members are created in the order of declaration, and destroyed in the opposite order.  (The order in initialization lists does not change order of creation, surprisingly).  So if you want `a` to outlive `b`, simply declare it first.

Answer (score 1):

Create an intermediate class.

```
 class PreFoo 
 {
   A* a:
    ...
 };

 class Foo : public PreFoo
 {
   B b;
   ...
 };
```

Comment: You need to make `a` protected or public and I would suggest private inheritance to match the original design.

Answer (score -2):

Edit: corrected mistake (thanks @Yakk)

You need to make `B` a pointer in `Foo` so you can control the order of deletion in the destructor OR make `A` a non-pointer and position it before `B` in the member order of `Foo`, so that it is destroyed after `B`, but this makes the code brittle as the order of member declaration is now important. Comment this in your code.

Comment: As I stated in the question, that I know this, but want to know if it's possible without doing this. (I edited the question to make this restriction clearer, in case it wasn't clear enough)

Comment: @Kritzefitz You have to make some modification to `Foo`, the only matter is what..

Comment: Sure I have to change something. But I don't know what options there are, besides the two I excluded. Maybe there is some more elegant solution, I didn't know about.